# Possible template & constexpr–if incompatibility

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr, if-constexpr

I wanted to calculate `e` value at compile–time (don't worry, not a homework), yet something went wrong.

```
template<size_t limit = 3, class result = std::ratio<0, 1>, size_t factorial = 1, size_t count = 1>
constexpr double e_impl() {
    if constexpr(limit == 0) {
        return static_cast<double>(result{}.num) / result{}.den;
    }
    return e_impl<limit - 1, std::ratio_add<result, std::ratio<1, factorial>>, factorial * count, count + 1>();
}
```

While calculated values are correct, compiler throws an error about overflow in template. It seems like `limit` variable goes out of range (below `0`), but it shouldn't happen as the `0`–case is being handled by the `if constexpr(…)` statement.

So the question is, am I wrong and that behavior should be expected, or is it a compiler bug? Compiled with GCC 7.1.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid the error, put the second return explicitly into the else branch:

```
template<size_t limit = 3, class result = std::ratio<0, 1>, size_t factorial = 1, size_t count = 1>
constexpr double e_impl() {
    if constexpr(limit == 0) {
        return static_cast<double>(result{}.num) / result{}.den;
    }
    else
    {
      return e_impl<limit - 1, std::ratio_add<result, std::ratio<1, factorial>>, factorial * count, count + 1>();
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/PdV7m7

Rational:

> During an instantiation of the enclosing function template or generic lambda, if the converted condition is true and the statement includes a constexpr else substatement, that substatement is not instantiated.

http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0128r1.html

It says nothing about an unconstrained else block, or a block which is not supposed to run, so it gets instantiated, throwing the error. (Note: also fails on clang)

Comment: A why would make this answer more useful.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not a bug.  The issue here is that even when `limit` is `0` and you stop the recursion the compiler still stamps out

```
return e_impl<limit - 1, std::ratio_add<result, std::ratio<1, factorial>>, factorial * count, count + 1>();
```

as it is unconditional.  You need to put it into a else block to get it only to compile when `limit` is not `0`.

```
template<size_t limit = 3, class result = std::ratio<0, 1>, size_t factorial = 1, size_t count = 1>
constexpr double e_impl() {
    if constexpr(limit == 0)
        return static_cast<double>(result{}.num) / result{}.den;
    else
        return e_impl<limit - 1, std::ratio_add<result, std::ratio<1, factorial>>, factorial * count, count + 1>();
}
```